# Get Top Record in Self Relationship

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, before-trigger

I have custom object called RoleLevel__c . Supervisor__c is self lookup in RoleLevel__c.
My requirement is to get the Top record in RoleLevel__c. for Example,

I am having records as below 
R1->R2->R3->R4->R5->R6->R7->R7->R8->R9->R10->R11

R11(record) have Supervisor__c  lookup to  R10(record),
R10(record) have Supervisor__c  lookup to  R9(record) like wise it goes

we have another field names TopRole__C which would be updated by before trigger 
based on the Supervisor__c  it gets the next record until Supervisor__c  become null ... currently we are achieving this functionality by SOQL inside while loop to get toprecord . Any possibility  to get the Top record without multiple SOQL ?
Iterating something like Supervisor__r.Supervisor__r.Supervisor__r.id did not work after 5 levels.
R1 , R2 names are used for example .

Answer (score 2):

Basically you could make use of the fact the the toprole__c is already populated on the new record's first parent. You could just copy that one, because it will have the same toprole__c as your new record. That will only require 1 SOQL query.

The key challenge is to keep all the toprole__c fields up-to-date, even if relationships at the top change (you already have this challenge right now). In order to do this, you could implement a trigger that checks if the supervisor__c field changes on a record. In that case, update the toprole__c field on that record to the new supervisor's toprole__c, and also trigger an update of the toprole__c field of all child records (the ones that have this record as supervisor__c).

This causes a chain of downward record updates, so depending on the volume of your data you might run into trouble there. The alternative would then be to do 1 query for all records with the same toprole__c field, build a tree in-memory (based on supervisor__c field) and decide which of the records need an update of the toprole__c field (only the ones that relate to the changed record).